# Mobile Connect - Destination Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I am trying to move data from a sales cloud data extension created with attributes in contact table to Mobile connect.
How do i create a destination Data extension with all the Mobile Connect fields ? What should be the table name ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you have a data extension and you would like to replicate it in Mobile Connect?

If that's the case Mobli Connect doesn't use data extensions but lists instead.
You can create an empty list first and then set up an import between that list and the data extension and with automation studio run that import as often you need it. This will allow you to transfer the data between the data extension and list in Mobile Connect.

Please let me know if you need further help with the setup.